# How to get company domain name for user from azure ad

Tags: azure-active-directory, powershell-3.0

How to retrieve details which contains information of login user including domain for example let say `domain\useralias` from Azure AD for a user input? Note that domain names are there in onprem ad which were sync to Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OnPremiseDistinguishedName extension property.

***Example:-***

```
    foreach($line in Get-Content c:\users\myuser\users.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        $onPremisesDistinguishedName = (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $line).get_item("onPremisesDistinguishedName")
        $domain = $onPremisesDistinguishedName.split(",")
        $alias = $line.Split("@")
        $sAMAccountName = ($domain[2]).Substring(3)
        $sAMAccountName + "\" + $alias[0]
    }
}
```